# Hangman game - how to do a "wrong guess" in c++?

Tags: c++

My game works but not the "wrong guess" part, that "error" means "it says I'm wrong even if my guess is right or it says wrong several times, not just once".

So, in my beginner program, that's where I'm stuck.

```
char u_recherche;  
std::string mot_secret(choisi_ton_mot.length(), '-');  
std::string choisi_ton_mot;  
int faute = 0;

 while (i < 999)                                       
    {
        //code

        for (int i = 0; i < mot_secret.length(); i++) // to check each letter
        {
            if (choisi_ton_mot[i] == u_recherche) //guess right
            {
                mot_secret[i] = u_recherche; // if right change "-" to the right letter
                std::cout << "lettre trouver ! " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        if (choisi_ton_mot[i] != u_recherche) //guess wrong
        {
            std::cout << "rater !" << std::endl;
            faute++;
        }
```

`

Comment: The posted code does not compile, at least in part because it is incomplete.

Comment: Please give us more detail or at least more code. Maybe your second if statement should be inside the for loop as well?

Comment: And again I can only recommend to use English when coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apart from that your code is not complete, the actual errors are easy to spot:

1. You have two loops. The outer "while" loop and the inner "for" loop. Those both use "i" as index, so the inner "i" hides the outer. This is not a bug in itself, but easily leads to other errors, like in your program.
2. Your second "if", the one that checks for a wrong guess, is outside the "for" loop, which means that the "i" used is the outer one, and not the one you want to use.
3. The wrong guess code should trigger only if right guess has not. One way to do this is to introduce a helper variable

So with this in mind, it could be rewritten to:

```
int tries = 0;
while (tries < 999)                                       
    {
        //code
        
        bool guess_wrong = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < mot_secret.length(); i++) // to check each letter
        {
            if (choisi_ton_mot[i] == u_recherche) //guess right
            {
                guess_wrong = false
                mot_secret[i] = u_recherche; // if right change "-" to the right letter
                std::cout << "lettre trouver ! " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        if (guess_wrong)
        {
            std::cout << "rater !" << std::endl;
            faute++;
        }
...
```

Comment: thanks you for your help, my question was very badly asked, i'm very glad you took your time to help me, i should delete this question know but if i do i couln't thanks you